# Java GUI progress bar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, processbuilder, jprogressbar

Hi I am trying to implement a progress bar into my java code. My java code consists of a graphical user interface that runs an executable file via processBuilder, and streamGobbler. When I implement this code for the progress bar:

```
private void updateProgressBar(final int newValue){

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            progressBar.setValue(newValue);
        }
    });

}
```

But it seems as though that the progress bar does not update while the executable is running in the background. I have also implemented processbuilder for the progress bar and that also has not worked. What should I do in order to have this progress bar to work.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like your executing your external process from the EDT, either that or the value you're passing `updateProgressBar` is invalid...

Comment: The value is inputted fine as it is a counter variable, so if it is via the EDT how do I go about it?

Comment: You would use a background thread do run your background process, such as one that is provided by a SwingWorker. Google "Concurrency in Swing" and check out the first hit for the important details.

Comment: Thank you this ended working. What I needed to do was separate my code files and my calculations to run in the background while the external program finished running.